# Defining new function to solve the original function easier.

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> If I have some $f : \mathbb A \to \mathbb A$ that needs to be solve. Can I define $g : \mathbb B \to \mathbb B$ when $\mathbb A$ is a subset of $\mathbb B$ and solve for $g(x)$ then I conclude that $f(x) = g(x)$?

For example , if I have $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$ , can I define $g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ so that when I get $g(x) = ???$ $\forall x \in \mathbb R$ , I’ll also get $f(x) = g(x)$ $\forall x \in \mathbb N$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not allowed.

Defining the domain over a larger set gives you more information, whereas defining the range over a larger set can allow more freedom in the function. Take for example, the functional equation
$$f(x+y) = f(x) + f(y)$$
for $f: \mathbb R^+ \to \mathbb R^+$. This only has linear solutions, but if you extend it to $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, there are nonlinear solutions.

Even if you use $\mathbb B \to \mathbb A$ instead of $\mathbb B \to \mathbb B$, there are other counterexamples; I'll leave this as an exercise for you to find.

Comment: Well, your example has $\Bbb A=\Bbb R^+$ and $\Bbb B=\Bbb R$. It ruens out that every solution $g\colon \Bbb \to\Bbb B$ that happens to map $\Bbb A\to\Bbb A$ gives a solution to the $\Bbb A\to\Bbb A$ problem, and every soltion can be obtained this way.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Indeed, this is why I suggested at the end that there are other counterexamples. For example, take $f: \mathbb N \to \mathbb N$, $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$. You'll find that $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb N$ only has constant solutions, if you use this functional equation, but $f$ over $\mathbb N$ certainly has functions not of this form (by choosing a different value for $f$ for each prime).